# Export jsf page to PDF

Tags: jsf, pdf, charts, export, reporting

I have a page with line and pie charts and I would like to generate a PDF report with those charts. How can I achieve this? I tried with `<p:dataExporter>`, but it works only on tables. Here is my code

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="70%"   >

                                    <p:chart type="line" model="#{reportMscBean.model}"  id="chart" style="width:700px;height:280px"/>  

  <p:separator></p:separator>
                                     <p:chart type="line" model="#{reportMscBean.model2}"  style="width:700px;height:280px" id="graphe2"/>

                        </p:layoutUnit>
                        <p:layoutUnit position="center"  size="30%" style="border:0px;">
                                    <p:chart type="pie" model="#{reportMscBean.pieModel2}"  style="width:250px;height:280px" id="pie2" >
                                    </p:chart>
                                    <p:separator></p:separator>

                                 <p:chart type="pie" model="#{reportMscBean.pieModel1}" style="width:250px;height:280px" id="pie1" >
                                    </p:chart>
                        </p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: please avoid creating duplicate accounts to ask the same question

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this just is not possible. Exports are basic. For complex exports, try a real reporting tool

Answer (score 0):

The `<p:dataExporter>` component you are using does only take data structured in a table, thus cannot work on an entire page. You could instead use some external libraries to achieve this. Take a look at *iText* for example, which is a common choice: [iText example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/generate-pdf-file-in-java-using-itext-jar/)